# Cyberoffice module from Dolibarr

Tags: php, module, prestashop, dolibarr

I have recently added a functionality developed by myself that consists on setting a caducity check on passwords for Dolibarr so they expire in 90 days. After developing through the different parts of the code it worked nice.

I have noticed that if I go to my prestashop and I set a new order it doesn't get registered on Dolibarr as it previously do.

These are the files I have touched:
`/main.inc`
`/core/lib/security2.lib.php`
`/core/login/functions_dolibarr.php`
`/user/card.php`
`/user/class/user.class.php`

I have tried to rollback some of the changes and I noticed that the only files that were giving me problems and didn't let me see new orders were:

/core/lib/security2.lib.php
/core/login/functions_dolibarr.php

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys, I solved it. It had nothing to do with Cyberoffice. I added a parameter in a login function and I didn't notice that Cyberoffice uses an user and a password so needs to use this function.